# Moc in mac show error message

Tags: macos, terminal, media-player, macports, jackd

I install [moc](http://moc.daper.net/) with [port](http://www.macports.org), but when try launche I get this error message.

$mocp 
Running the server...
Trying JACK...
FATAL_ERROR: No valid sound driver
FATAL_ERROR: Server exited

any idea ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install jack.  I think I used JackOSX, but there is also a jack available from macports.  Once it's installed, you'll need to run it from the terminal before loading moc.  I usually use this command :

```
jackd -d coreaudio &
```

then you can load mocp.

Don't forget to build moc with vorbis:

```
port uninstall moc
port clean moc
port install moc +vorbis
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the vorbis variant you do not need to unsinstall moc. Instead, use this command:

```
sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants moc +vorbis
```